# Angular2 View is not updating to reflect the object (row) I just removed from the array (table)

Tags: arrays, angular, view

I am trying to delete an object from my API. The delete function works, and I can remove it from both the API and the array of objects that it is stored in to display in the view.

I have this delete method in my controller that is called when the delete button in the row is clicked.

```
onDelete(category) {
let index = this.categories.indexOf(category);

if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?")) {
  this.categoryService.deleteCategory(category.id)
    .then(category => {
      this.categories.splice(index, 1);
  });
}
```

}

Category is an object that is passed in from the html template.

```
        <td><button class="icon-myfont-48" value="X" (click)="onDelete(category)"></button></td>
```

If I do a console.log(this.categories) before the this.categories.splice(index,1); then I see 7 objects in my array, and if I console.log after, I see 6. So the splice is working and it's removing my data from the array, but I have to refresh the page or navigate to another page to get the view to update.

What am I missing here? I've tried using ApplicationRef.tick() and ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() to force the view to update, but nothing works so far. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try using filter and replacing the array completely. Something similar to this code snippet perhaps     :                `this.categories = this.categories.filter((c) => c.id != category.id);`

Comment: hey, that worked! I just passed in the category.id from the view instead of the whole object and used "id" in the snippet you provided instead of category.id.

thank you so much!

Comment: Cool! I'll move it to an answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using filter and replace the array completely. Something similar to this code snippet perhaps :

```
this.categories = this.categories.filter((c) => c.id != category.id);
```